# Getting error while inserting date in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I am trying to insert my data in database using stored procedure but i am getting error.

My code to store data is like this:

```
public string InsertJobData(JobDTO jobdata)
    {
        try
        {
            DbManager.OpenConnection();
            DbManager.AddParameter("JobId", jobdata.JobType, StoredProcedureParameterDirection.Input);
            DbManager.AddParameter("JobTypeId", jobdata.JobTypeId, StoredProcedureParameterDirection.Input);

            if (jobdata.JobRefence != null)
            {
                DbManager.AddParameter("JobRefence", jobdata.JobRefence, StoredProcedureParameterDirection.Input);
            }

            else
            {
                DbManager.AddParameter("JobRefence", DBNull.Value, StoredProcedureParameterDirection.Input);
            }

            DbManager.AddParameter("JobName", jobdata.JobName, StoredProcedureParameterDirection.Input);
            DbManager.AddParameter("CustomerName", jobdata.CustomerName, StoredProcedureParameterDirection.Input);
            DbManager.AddParameter("Quantity", jobdata.Quantity, StoredProcedureParameterDirection.Input);
            DbManager.AddParameter("JobDescription", jobdata.JobDescription, StoredProcedureParameterDirection.Input);
            DbManager.AddParameter("CreatedOn", jobdata.CreatedOn, StoredProcedureParameterDirection.Input);

            if (jobdata.CompleteOn != null)
            {
                DbManager.AddParameter("CompleteOn", jobdata.CompleteOn, StoredProcedureParameterDirection.Input);
            }

            else
            {
                DbManager.AddParameter("CompleteOn", DBNull.Value, StoredProcedureParameterDirection.Input);
            }

            DbManager.AddParameter("Department", jobdata.Department, StoredProcedureParameterDirection.Input);
            DbManager.AddParameter("DepartmentId", jobdata.DepartmentId, StoredProcedureParameterDirection.Input);
            DbManager.AddParameter("Status", jobdata.Status, StoredProcedureParameterDirection.Input);

            if (jobdata.AreaOfPCB != null)
            {
                DbManager.AddParameter("AreaOfPCB", jobdata.AreaOfPCB, StoredProcedureParameterDirection.Input);
            }

            else
            {
                DbManager.AddParameter("AreaOfPCB", DBNull.Value, StoredProcedureParameterDirection.Input);
            }


            if (jobdata.NumberOfJoints != null)
            {
                DbManager.AddParameter("NumberOfJoints", jobdata.NumberOfJoints, StoredProcedureParameterDirection.Input);
            }

            else
            {
                DbManager.AddParameter("NumberOfJoints", DBNull.Value, StoredProcedureParameterDirection.Input);
            }

            DbManager.AddParameter("TaskStatus", jobdata.Tasktypeid, StoredProcedureParameterDirection.Input);
            DbManager.AddParameter("Id", StoredProcedureParameterDirection.Output);
            DbManager.ExecuteNonQuery("spInsertJobData", System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            jobdata.Id = (int)DbManager.GetParameter("Id");

            jobdata.NewJobId = jobdata.JobType + "_" + jobdata.Id;

            //dbManager.AddParameter("JobId", jobdata.JobType, StoredProcedureParameterDirection.Input);
            //dbManager.ExecuteNonQuery("spUpdateJobByJobId", System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);

        }

        catch
        {

        }

        finally
        {
            DbManager.CloseConnection();
        }

        return jobdata.NewJobId;
    }
```

My proprty class is like this:

```
 public int Id { get; set; }
    public string JobId { get; set; }
    public int JobTypeId { get; set; }
    public string JobRefence { get; set; }
    public string JobName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string JobDescription { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CompleteOn { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public string JobType { get; set; }
    public string NewJobId { get; set; }
    public float? AreaOfPCB { get; set; }
    public int? NumberOfJoints { get; set; }
    public int? Tasktypeid { get; set; }
```

My stored procedure is like this:

`

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[spInsertJobData]
@JobId nvarchar(50),
@JobTypeId int,
@JobRefence nvarchar(50),
@JobName nvarchar(50),
@CustomerName nvarchar(50),
@Quantity bigint,
@JobDescription nvarchar(MAX),
@CreatedOn datetime,
@CompleteOn datetime,
@Department nvarchar(50),
@DepartmentId int,
@Status bit,
@AreaOfPCB int,
@NumberOfJoints bigint,
@TaskStatus int,
@Id int OUTPUT
As
BEGIN
INSERT INTO oms.JobId_Table (JobId,JobTypeId,JobRefence,JobName,CustomerName,Quantity,JobDescription,CreatedOn,CompleteOn,Department,DepartmentId,Status,AreaOfPCB,NumberOfJoints,TaskStatus)
VALUES (@JobId,@JobTypeId,@JobRefence,@JobName,@CustomerName,@Quantity,@JobDescription,@CreatedOn,@CompleteOn,@Department,@DepartmentId,@Status,@AreaOfPCB,@NumberOfJoints,@TaskStatus)
UPDATE oms.JobId_Table
SET JobId = 'oms.' + Convert(varchar,@JobId) +'_'+ Convert(varchar,oms.JobId_Table.Id)
WHERE JobId = @JobId
SET @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
RETURN  @Id
END`
```

When i execute the code, it throws following exception:
[image]

Please help.
Thanks in Advance.

More details about exception:`

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was caught
  HResult=-2146232060
  Message=Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
  ErrorCode=-2146232060
  Class=16
  LineNumber=0
  Number=8114
  Procedure=spInsertJobData
  Server=JITENDERSINGH\JITENDER
  State=5
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
       at Company.Project.Entities.Entities.DatabaseHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(String query, CommandType commandtype, DatabaseConnectionState connectionstate) in e:\SGS_MVC_APP\SGS_PROJECT\Company.Project.Entities\Entities\DBHelper.cs:line 258
       at Company.Project.Entities.Entities.DatabaseHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(String query, CommandType commandtype) in e:\SGS_MVC_APP\SGS_PROJECT\Company.Project.Entities\Entities\DBHelper.cs:line 221
       at Company.Project.Entities.Entities.DBManager.ExecuteNonQuery(String query, CommandType commandtype) in e:\SGS_MVC_APP\SGS_PROJECT\Company.Project.Entities\Entities\DBManagerBase.cs:line 131
       at Company.Project.DataAccess.BiddingFirstStepDAC.InsertJobData(JobDTO jobdata) in e:\SGS_MVC_APP\SGS_PROJECT\Company.Project.DataAccess\BiddingFirstStepDAC.cs:line 163
  InnerException:
```

`

Comment: Can you post the exception detail?

Comment: Can you check whether any of the other values like `JobId` etc are `null`? That could cause various problems, since they aren't tweaked to `DbNull.Value`

Comment: Note: the `SET @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()` should ideally **immediately** follow the `INSERT`. That won't cause this problem, though.

Comment: @M.Hassan Sir which kind of detail you require as i have given you the screenshot of the exception.

Comment: I think they mean the "View Detail..." - however, since this is coming from the RDBMS, I doubt that there is anything more to see

Comment: @MarcGravell No SIr, jobId n all are not null. They have values but i don't know why it's giving error of converting nvarchar to datetime.

Comment: Click "copy exception detail to the clipboard" and post the text. You get more information that reference your source code.

Comment: Can I safely assume that in the database, the only columns that are `datetime` are `CreatedOn` and `CompleteOn`?

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah,only two columns are datetime.

Comment: How does `DbManager` manage the parameter data types?

Comment: @Crowcoder ADO.NET will usually infer them for well-known types, but it is a valid question; I'd be very interested to know what `DbManager` is in this case (because it looks *absolutely horrible*, IMO)

Comment: To rule out a few things, could you try something for me? Specifically, replace `{value}` with `((object){value))??DBNull.Value` in all `AddParameter` cases? So `jobdata.JobType` would become `((object)jobdata.JobType)??DBNull.Value` ? This will make it clear whether or not nulls are the problem (combined with pass-by-position vs pass-by-name)

Comment: Also: what is the provider in this case? is it `SqlClient`? or ODBC? or...?

Comment: Additional thought: is it deliberate that `@JobId` is passed the `JobType` value, not the `JobId` value?

Comment: I found in the exception detail that error is raised from DBHelper class. and others. Try to review the source code line number. Also review the sent sql statement from sql profiller. It's very helpful to fix the root problem.

Comment: Also, be sure from datetime format .In many cases this may be the cause. I expect if you review the sql  from sql profiller , you will fix who is the string field.

Comment: @MarcGravell I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @M.Hassan Sir i don't know how to use sql profiler.

Comment: Can you dump the sql statement. Run sql profiler tool for sql server. It should be your first tool to know how DAL generate sql to server.

Comment: for sql profileer, read: 
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/272/profiler-and-server-side-traces/  and 
https://thefirstsql.com/2011/01/07/sql-server-profiler-a-tutorial/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you use generic Data access layer ,DbManger,Dbhelper and other classes,which handle the parameter type, plus stored  procedure handle many string columns, to fix such a problem quickly, my advice:

- Review sql statement sent to the server from DAL using sql profiller. itis your friend tool.
- Review the exception details, and trace source line number to know source of error.
- Very important: DAL should handle exception in a way to log errors in a log file, with exception detail and the name/value/type of parameters, to help fix problems. It's not enough to catch the generic exception sent from the server.
- DAl should convert string (of DateTime columns)  to DateTime based on DateTime format of the server. For safety YYYYMMDD is the standared, whatever the format of the regional datetime in the client.
- You should do a Unit test. And update your tests as new error/bugs appear.

**Edit:**

From the data type of the the stored procedure , only @CreatedOn and @CompleteOn are datetime type, so they may be the source of the error.

I guess: datetime format of these columns don't match server datetime format
Let the sql profiler tell us what is going on.

**Edit 2:**

DbManager.AddParameter doesn't pas the sql data type of the parameter,  which insure data conversion correctly bet client and server.
It should  be:

```
  param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime;
```

As a Proof of Concept , i run stored procedure named "[Sales by Year]" in northwind database in c# ado.net application and pass parameters.

My SQL Server (sql 2012) datetime format is: mdy

to get: run the command

```
dbcc useroptions
```

you get (in my case)

```
dateformat  mdy
```

if passed datetime in mdy or ymd(universal format) , it's accepted by server withou errors.

if passed the  datatime in dmy format (which is different than server), it will raise an error:

```
Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.
```

I modified the datetime format of Ending_Date and run different cases, as follows:

```
//   var date2= DateTime.Today.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy"); //ok match server
//var date2 = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yy"); //error don't match server format
var date2 = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"); //error don't match server
var date2 = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd"); //ok universal datetime format
```

when i review the result of sql profiler (in a glance i can catch the sql and fix  the error), I found:

Output of SQL Profiler:

valid

```
exec [dbo].[Sales by Year] @Beginning_Date=N'1970/1/1',@Ending_Date=N'July 20, 2016'
exec [dbo].[Sales by Year] @Beginning_Date=N'1970/1/1',@Ending_Date=N'7/20/2016 12:00:00 AM'
exec [dbo].[Sales by Year] @Beginning_Date=N'1970/1/1',@Ending_Date='2016-07-20 00:00:00'
exec [dbo].[Sales by Year] @Beginning_Date=N'1970/1/1',@Ending_Date=N'20160720'
```

Invalid with error:

```
exec [dbo].[Sales by Year] @Beginning_Date=N'1970/1/1',@Ending_Date=N'20-07-2016'
```

**Conclusion:**

Set variables of datetime in format typical to server or in the  universal format ymd

So,  modify your code as:

```
DbManager.AddParameter("CreatedOn", jobdata.CreatedOn.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), StoredProcedureParameterDirection.Input);

DbManager.AddParameter("CompleteOn", jobdata.CompleteOn.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), StoredProcedureParameterDirection.Input);
```

I hope that help in resolving your problem

**Edit 3: Handling Null values**

You already handle, in your code, null values for  jobdata.CompleteOn, so do the same  for jobdata.CreatedOn

```
if (jobdata.CreatedOn != null)
        {
            DbManager.AddParameter("CreatedOn", jobdata.CreatedOn.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), StoredProcedureParameterDirection.Input);
        }
        else
        {
            DbManager.AddParameter("CreatedOn", DBNull.Value, StoredProcedureParameterDirection.Input);
        }
```

Note:

1) As jobdata.CreatedOn may be null,  It's better , to declare jobdata.CreatedOn as nullable , by using DateTime?

```
public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
```

2)  other method to format DateTime:

```
var createon=  string.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}",jobdata.CreatedOn));
```

Comment: Its giving me error as i have nullable datetime completeon. If i make it non nullable then your solution is working but with nullable it's not working.

Comment: So,my guess target the root problem :) , I will Edit my post to handle nullable datetime cases.

Comment: ok..thanks..i'll mark it as answer because it solved my half error.

Comment: what is the other half error. Read my new note in the post.

Comment: I give to different way to format DateTime based on if nullable or not. Is it clear?